# Question: about postcss-plugin-px2rem exclude

Tags: webpack, postcss

when using postcss-plugin-px2rem, I wanna exclude a folder named picker. According to the documents I read, I Code as follow:

exclude: /(picker)/,

It works. But i have a confuse. What if there are two folders named picker, and they're in different paths, like 'src/components/picker' and 'src/modules/page/components/picker', and I wanna exclude only one of them. How should I code? Can the plugin handle these situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

/src\\components\\picker/

Answer (score 0):

Yes!
The item you pass to the exclude option is a regex parameter. 
During execution the plugin checks your regex against every path and if it matches it's excluded.

In your example: if your path contains the word "picker" it will be excluded, in your case both folders.

If you'd like to exclude only one of them, you need to adjust your regex to `/src\/components\/picker/` for example, if you only want the second path to be handled by the plugin.

See https://regex101.com/r/w6wepR/1 for tinkering around